# Setting Angular 5 PWA Caching Time to unlimited

Tags: angular, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

the cache of my pwa(Progressive Web App) gets deleted after 3 days. Is there a way to tell the browser that the cache should never be deleted?

My ngsw-config.json looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "dataGroups": [{
            "name": "api-freshness",
            "urls": [
                "/timeline"
            ],
            "cacheConfig": {
                "strategy": "freshness",
                "maxSize": 100,
                "maxAge": "3d",
                "timeout": "10s"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "api-performance",
            "urls": [
                "/favorites"
            ],
            "cacheConfig": {
                "strategy": "performance",
                "maxSize": 100,
                "maxAge": "3d"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can i somehow set the maxAge to unlimited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b78ada198add37827fd56c284ce6ab8fc4988180/aio/content/guide/service-worker-configref.md#maxage) specifies that `maxAge` is required and it's [parsed](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/90d1423fb46a26ffe24ec868e56483a5fd046a78/packages/service-worker/config/src/generator.ts#L90) using a [method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/90d1423fb46a26ffe24ec868e56483a5fd046a78/packages/service-worker/config/src/duration.ts#L12) that requires input similar to `3d12h`. However you could use a value like `365d` and for all practical purposes it'll be "unlimited".